# Layout Designing in android

Tags: android, android-layout

can we design an footer like this(see the attached image), images in footer looks like popping out of one layout to another layout.

[image]

Could anybody let me know how to design like this and if possible some code examples.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to reuse the same layout around your application is to use the include directive. Something like this:

```
<include layout="@layout/my_footer" />
```

Where my_footer.xml is your footer layout.

In the detail you can achieve that layout using a simple LinearLayour horizontally oriented:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal">
     <ImageButton android:layout_weight="1"/>
     <ImageButton android:layout_weight="1"/>
     <ImageButton android:layout_weight="1"/>
     <ImageButton android:layout_weight="1"/>
     <ImageButton android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

You can find further information about reusing layout here: http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-2-reusing-layouts.html

P.S. Note the attribute layout_weight which give the same width to all your LinearLayour child.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume the footer is footer-layout & footer-layout is under body-layout.

Now use a background image which will have 2 rows, the color of the first row must match with the color of body-layout, and the second row of the image will be black color.

Use this image as background of footer-layout & design it with ImageButtons as you want.

This will give you the above mentioned visual effects.

Comment: when the screen size gets bigger the image will be distorted and the same footer cannot be used for different devices.